# Bootstrap datepicker shadows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker, box-shadow

I have next problem:
  cant add box-shadow under circles. I know that circles(radial-gradient) are not on whole td element that is why white circle appears at every picked element. ( image added [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcNcc.jpg) )

How can I add straight under the radial-gradient element

css:

```
td.active  {
background-color: none !important;
border-radius: 50% !important;
background: radial-gradient(circle closest-side,#ff5200 1.1em,white 1.16em ) !important;
  box-shadow:  0px 13px 53px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.52);   
}
```

html:

```
<div id="datePicker" datepicker-mode="'month'">
    <input ng-show="false" type="text"  class="form-control date"/>
</div>
```

Js :

```
$("#datePicker").datepicker({ todayHighlight: true, viewMode: 'days', multidate: true, startDate: '+15d', endDate: '+105d'});
```

Comment: Please provide your HTML too and also, replicate what you have so far in jsFiddle.

Comment: Updated with html and js and result you can see on image http://i.stack.imgur.com/OcNcc.jpg